# Error when converting JSON HTTP POST request to Java object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jackson, httprequest

I would like to convert an HTTP POST request body (in JSON) to a Java object.

I am using this Java code for the server-side:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
clip = mapper.readValue(request.body(), Clip.class);
```

while the JavaScript (jQuery) client-side code is:

```
$.post("/insertClip", { "item": item.value, "value":value.value, "dimension":dimension.value });
```

When I run the application, this error appears:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: clips.json; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1433)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:442)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._handleUnexpectedValue(Utf8StreamParser.java:2090)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._nextTokenNotInObject(Utf8StreamParser.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.nextToken(Utf8StreamParser.java:492)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2770)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2718)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1817)
    at elements.DefinitedRoute$2.handle(DefinitedRoute.java:63)
    at spark.webserver.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:133)
    at spark.webserver.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1068)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:807)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:528)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Why am I not able to convert this POST request to a Java object?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `request.body()`? Looks like the JSON is being malformed somewhere along the way

Comment: The content of the `request.body()` should be this: `{ "item": item.value, "value":value.value, "dimension":dimension.value }`

Comment: It *should* be, but you would need to print it out from the server and double check because it just looks like it can't parse the JSON.

Comment: Thank you,  I have solved the problem adding the JSON.stringify() method in the jQuery code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem adding the JSON.stringify() method in the jQuery code:

```
 $.post("http://localHost:4567/insertClip", 
JSON.stringify({ "item": item.value , "value":value.value, "dimension":dimension.value }));
```

Thanks.